# How to generate components dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, generics, frontend, dynamic-programming

I have created generic funtion that render material table for me I just need to provide: datasource, column etc. This table is working fine for now, this is how it's looks like.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ingh.png

That how my data for this table looks like:

```
  public displayedColumns: TableColumnDto[] =
    [
      { title: 'ID', objectField: 'id' },
      { title: 'Customer name', objectField: 'customerName' },
      { title: 'Total value', objectField: 'totalValue' },
      { title: 'Payment type', objectField: 'paymentType' },
      { title: 'Status', objectField: 'status' },
      { title: 'Date', objectField: 'date', pipeValues: { pipe: DatePipe, pipeArgs: 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm' }, contentMode: ContentMode.dynamicPipe },
      {
        title: '', objectField: 'action',
        customContent: TableButtonsComponent,
        contentMode: ContentMode.custom,
        injectorType: TableButtonsDto
      }
    ];
```

As you can see in last entry i want to provide custom component that contains buttons. Every table which will be created can have different component with buttons. So I have created new component with buttons

```
import { Component, , Input, OnInit, } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'order-table-buttons',
    template: `
    <!-- {{element}} -->
    <button mat-button mat-icon-button (click) ="onFactureClick()">
        <mat-icon mat-icon style="color: rgb(133, 77, 14)">description</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <button class="mat-icon-button" mat-icon-button (click) ="onDeleteClick()">
     <mat-icon mat-icon class="mat-icon" style="color: red">delete</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <button mat-stroked-button (click) ="onDetailsClick()">Details</button>`
})
export class TableButtonsComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() data!: number;
    constructor() {
    }
    // public element: TableButtonsDto
    ngOnInit() {
    }

    public onFactureClick(): void {
        console.log('facture' + this.data);
    }

    public onDeleteClick(): void {
        console.log('delete' + this.data);
    }

    public onDetailsClick(): void {
        console.log('details' + this.data);
    }
}
```

And the question is how can I:

1. Display/render this component in table for every row
2. Pass data to this component in every row (probably it will be id everytime)